# How to get the user count which failed in jmeter

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

I have set up the following in Jmeter:

```
Number of threads = 10
Ramp period = 100
Loop count = 100
```

There are 5 http requests in test-plan.

When I run the test  I get an error at say 153rd user.
How can I get the number (153) in Jmeter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Error listner which will tell you details that your test failed for 153rd User.

https://github.com/balajiciyer/JMeter-Error-Listener?goback=%2Egde_2017104_member_212501240

You can get details on above link.